# Android Layout How to have TextView start at the top of the parent

Tags: android, layout, vertical-alignment

Hello Android developers, I have a layout with 4 TextViews and 4 Views (for line spacer).  I cannot get the view to start at the top of the layout.  It is always centered vertically.  I tried Constraint Layout, Linear Layout and Relative Layout with different attributes for each type that seems like it should work.  In Android Studio (Artic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4) Layout Designer it looks perfect but running on several different devices (virtual and physical) the TextViews are always centered in the device.  Here is my current layout using Constraint Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.preciousMetalsInventory.Settings.SettingsMainFragment"
    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_metal_type_maintenance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/text_metal_type_setting"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_secondary_variant"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/settings_main_divider1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/action_metal_type_maintenance"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_item_shape_maintenance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/text_item_shape_setting"
        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_secondary_variant"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/settings_main_divider1"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/settings_main_divider2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        android:layout_below="@id/action_item_shape_maintenance"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/action_item_shape_maintenance"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_uom_maintenance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/settings_main_divider2"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/text_unit_of_measure_setting"
        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_secondary_variant"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/settings_main_divider2"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/settings_main_divider3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/action_uom_maintenance"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_source_maintenance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/text_source_settings"
        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_secondary_variant"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/settings_main_divider3"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and screen shots
Design Editor:
[image]

and Device capture:
[image]

I've spent many hours on this searching and trying every way I can find.

Thanks.

Never thought about the problem being somewhere else.  Yes this is a fragment layout and here are the activity layout files, fragment and theme (could be the theme?)

Fragment:

```
package com.preciousMetalsInventory.Settings;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;
import com.preciousMetalsInventory.R;


public class SettingsMainFragment extends Fragment
{
    Context context;
    Fragment meFrag;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this.getContext();
        meFrag = this;

        OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true /* enabled by default */)
        {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed()
            {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(meFrag).popBackStack();
            }
        };
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings_main, container, false);
        ItemTypeMaintenanceViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ItemTypeMaintenanceViewModel.class);

        TextView metalTypes = view.findViewById(R.id.action_metal_type_maintenance);
        metalTypes.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
            viewModel.SetSettingType(SettingType.MetalType);
            NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
                    .navigate((R.id.action_settingsMainFragment_to_itemTypeMaintenanceFragment));
        });

        TextView itemShapes = view.findViewById(R.id.action_item_shape_maintenance);
        itemShapes.setOnClickListener(tView -> {
            viewModel.SetSettingType(SettingType.ItemShape);
            NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
                    .navigate((R.id.action_settingsMainFragment_to_itemTypeMaintenanceFragment));
        });

        TextView uoms = view.findViewById(R.id.action_uom_maintenance);
        uoms.setOnClickListener(tView -> {
            viewModel.SetSettingType(SettingType.ItemUnitOfMeasure);
            NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
                    .navigate((R.id.action_settingsMainFragment_to_itemTypeMaintenanceFragment));
        });

        TextView source = view.findViewById(R.id.action_source_maintenance);
        source.setOnClickListener(tView -> {
            viewModel.SetSettingType(SettingType.Source);
            NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
                    .navigate((R.id.action_settingsMainFragment_to_itemTypeMaintenanceFragment));
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Activity layout files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/PlatinumTint"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/design_default_color_secondary_variant"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/design_default_color_secondary_variant"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_main"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.preciousMetalsInventory.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MetalsInventory.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.MetalsInventory.PopupOverlay" />


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="176dp"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/nav_header_title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nav_header_subtitle" />
</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_action_home"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_list_inventory"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_action_inventory"
            android:title="@string/menu_list_inventory" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_new_item"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_action_add_box"
            android:title="@string/menu_add_metal" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_action_settings"
            android:title="@string/menu_settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_import_inventory"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_action_file_download"
            android:title="@string/menu_import_inventory" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_export_inventory"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_action_file_upload"
            android:title="@string/menu_export_inventory" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_metal_summary"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_action_sort"
            android:title="@string/menu_metal_type_summary" />

    </group>
</menu>
```

Theme:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Metals" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/teal_700</item>
        <!--        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>-->
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!--        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/SilverTint</item>-->
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <!--        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>-->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Metals.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Metals.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.Metals.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="MySpinnerDatePickerStyle" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
        <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MySpinnerDatePicker</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MySpinnerDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.DatePicker">
        <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MetalsInventory.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.MetalsInventory.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

You got me looking in the right direction.  I changed content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

from
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
to
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"

That pushed *everything* up and now some of the fragment layouts are underneath the app bar so some experimenting there.  Stay tuned.

Comment: That layout is for a `Fragment`, yeah? Are you sure the problem isn't with the `Activity` layout?

Comment: Please show the layout into which this one is going (like the fragment and / or activity) it's ultimately living in.

Comment: Wow never thought about that, I may be too focused on one specific area.

Comment: Added the fragment, layout files and theme.  Sorry, I lumped the three (chained) Activity layout files and the nav_header_main and activity_main_drawer together.  I can edit that if it will help.  Thanks

Comment: oh my, I need new glasses.  In my last edit I just noticed that  I already had app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" in the <fragment attribute, so I just removed the app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" and everything is perfect.  Thank you for putting me in the right direction.

Comment: Cool. I'd also point out that you probably have too many ConstraintLayouts. You generally shouldn't need it in the activity layout file to wrap the Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mike M. and dominicoder for showing me where to look for the problem. I discovered that I had app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" and app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" in the Activity Layout file content_main.xml.  I guess this is one way to easily center all views in Fragment layouts.  I removed the app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" and every all views moved up to the top of the layout where I wanted them.

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```